# How do I use the "group_by_window" function in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In TensorFlow's new set of input pipeline functions, there is an ability to group sets of records together using the "group_by_window" function. It is described in the documentation here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset#group_by_window

I don't fully understand the explanation here used to describe the function, and I tend to learn best by example. I can't find any example code anywhere on the internet for this function. Could someone please whip up a barebones and runnable example of this function to show how it works, and what to give this function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For tensorflow version 1.9.0
Here is a quick example I could come up with:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
components = np.arange(100).astype(np.int64)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(components)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.group_by_window(key_func=lambda x: x%2, reduce_func=lambda _, els: els.batch(10), window_size=100)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
features = iterator.get_next()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(features) # array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18], dtype=int64)
```

The first argument `key_func` maps every element in the dataset to a key.

The `window_size` defines the bucket size that is given to the `reduce_fund`.

In the `reduce_func` you receive a block of `window_size` elements. You can shuffle, batch or pad however you want.

EDIT for dynamic padding and bucketing using the group_by_window fucntion [more here](https://github.com/maximedb/InstaCorrect/blob/master/Model/input_functions.py) :

If you have a `tf.contrib.dataset` which holds `(sequence, sequence_length, label)` and sequence is a tensor of tf.int64:

```
def bucketing_fn(sequence_length, buckets):
    """Given a sequence_length returns a bucket id"""
    t = tf.clip_by_value(buckets, 0, sequence_length)
    return tf.argmax(t)

def reduc_fn(key, elements, window_size):
    """Receives `window_size` elements"""
    return elements.shuffle(window_size, seed=0)
# Create buckets from 0 to 500 with an increment of 15 -> [0, 15, 30, ... , 500]
buckets = [tf.constant(num, dtype=tf.int64) for num in range(0, 500, 15)
window_size = 1000
# Bucketing
dataset = dataset.group_by_window(
        lambda x, y, z: bucketing_fn(x, buckets), 
        lambda key, x: reduc_fn(key, x, window_size), window_size)
# You could pad it in the reduc_func, but I'll do it here for clarity
# The last element of the dataset is the dynamic sentences. By giving it tf.Dimension(None) it will pad the sencentences (with 0) according to the longest sentence.
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes=(
        tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([]), tf.Dimension(None)))
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
features = iterator.get_next()
```

Comment: `key_func=lambda x: x%2` maps x to either 0 and 1, right? I don't understand why the result has only even elements?

Comment: Yes. It basically creates two buckets: one for even and one for odd. There are only even element in first print statement because it took elements from the even bucket for this batch

Comment: Hi @MaximeDeBruyn could you explain why you have ```lambda x, y, z: bucketing_fn(x, buckets)``` and ```lambda key, x: reduc_fn(key, x, window_size), window_size)```? what would be wrong with just passing the functions, instead of lambda?